# "Workflow Lookup" for Current Item in SharePoint Online Site Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have a SharePoint Designer site workflow and I can't find 'Current Item' Option in the Data Source. Is this not available? This is a 2013 Site workflow on a SharePoint online site.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Site workflows are not attached to any items. They are triggered by events from the site. Because of this there is no item that is currently processing

Comment: Thank you. I was actually using a reusable workflow but I need to call it inside another workflow, that's why I picked site workflow option.

Comment: There is no option to call a Reusable workflow inside a workflow. it has to be a list or site workflow. And now the site workflow cannot do what I want. I want to sit down and cry, honestly!